# How to truncate a string in python including a truncated word in the result?

Tags: python, string

There is an excellent discussion here [Truncate a string without ending in the middle of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250357/truncate-a-string-without-ending-in-the-middle-of-a-word) on how to do a 'smart' string truncation in python.
But the problem with the solutions proposed there is that if the width limit falls within a word, then this word is thrown off completely.

How can I truncate a string in python setting a 'soft' width limit, i.e. if the limit falls in the middle of the word, then this word **is kept**?

Example:

```py
str = "it's always sunny in philadelphia"
trunc(str, 7)
>>> it's always...
```

My initial thinking is to slice the string up to the soft limit and then start checking every next character, adding it to the slice until I encounter a whitespace character. But this seems extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def trunc(ipt, length, suffix='...'):
  if " " in ipt[length-1: length]:
    # The given length puts us on a word boundary
    return ipt[:length].rstrip(' ') + suffix

  # Otherwise add the "tail" of the input, up to just before the first space it contains
  return ipt[:length] + ipt[length:].partition(" ")[0] + suffix

s = "it's always sunny in philadelphia"  # Best to avoid 'str' as a variable name, it's a builtin
for n in (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13):
  print(f"{n}: {trunc(s, n)}")
```

which outputs:

```
1: it's...
4: it's...
5: it's...
6: it's always...
7: it's always...
12: it's always...
13: it's always sunny...
```

Note the behaviour of the 5 and 12 cases: this code assumes that you want to eliminate the space that would appear before the "...".

Comment: Good point for `str` variable naming, for some reason I thought the builtin was `string`

Comment: And then I called a param `input` :D Fixed that now!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I missed the answer provided in the linked post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250471/3678257) by Markus Jarderot

```py
def smart_truncate2(text, min_length=100, suffix='...'):
    """If the `text` is more than `min_length` characters long,
    it will be cut at the next word-boundary and `suffix`will
    be appended.
    """
    pattern = r'^(.{%d,}?\S)\s.*' % (min_length-1)
    return re.sub(pattern, r'\1' + suffix, text)
```

It runs for

`3.49 µs ± 25.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)`

@slothrop's solution runs for:

`897 ns ± 3.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)`

which is quite faster